# LaTeX: How do I create numbered sections for Bibliography, listoffigures, listoftables and lstlistoflistings?

Tags: latex

I try to have the content mentioned in the title as sections and not as their own chapters. Numbered if possible.

I tried the following but then they where all twice in the table of content and they were sections of the bibliography. The renewcommand with lstlistoflistings is something I tried. The other two work and I couldn't find anything for the bibliography.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, abstract=on, listof=totocnumbered]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tocbasic}

\renewcommand*{\listoffigures}{\listoftoc[\listfigurename]{lof}}
\renewcommand*{\listoftables}{\listoftoc[\listtablename]{lot}}
\renewcommand*{\lstlistoflistings}{\listoftoc[\lstlistlistingname]{lol}}

\setuptoc{lof}{leveldown,totoc}
\setuptoc{lot}{leveldown,totoc}
\setuptoc{lol}{leveldown,totoc}

\chapter{Verzeichnisse}
\renewcommand{\clearpage}{}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Literaturverzeichnis}
\printbibliography[heading=bibnumbered, title=Literaturverzeichnis]
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abbildungsverzeichnis}
\listoffigures
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Tabellenverzeichnis}
\listoftables
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Verzeichnis der Code-Listings}
\lstlistoflistings
\newpage
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to include a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) please? Your code as it is won't compile so we can't copy/paste it to our own systems to trial solutions/debug etc

Comment: Found a solution.
It is ugly but works.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution

```
\documentclass[a4paper, abstract=on, listof=totocnumbered]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{tocbasic}

\defbibheading{subbibliography}{%
    \section{Literaturverzeichnis}}

\renewcommand*{\listoffigures}{\listoftoc[\listfigurename]{lof}}
\renewcommand*{\listoftables}{\listoftoc[\listtablename]{lot}}
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{Listing}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\lstlistoflistings}{%
    \begingroup
    \clearpage
    \section{\lstlistlistingname% Taken from `article.cls`....
        \@mkboth{%
            \MakeUppercase\lstlistlistingname}{\MakeUppercase   
            \lstlistlistingname}
    }%
    \@starttoc{lol}
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\setuptoc{lof}{leveldown,totoc}
\setuptoc{lot}{leveldown,totoc}

\chapter{Verzeichnisse}
\printbibliography[title=Literaturverzeichnis, heading=subbibliography]
\newpage


\listoffigures
\newpage

\listoftables
\newpage

\lstlistoflistings
```